# When has discrete understanding preceded continuous?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, ho.history-overview, discrete-geometry, big-list

From my limited perspective, it appears that the understanding
of a mathematical phenomenon has usually been achieved,
historically, in a continuous setting
before it was fully explored in a discrete setting.
An example I have in mind is the relatively recent activity in
[discrete differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_differential_geometry), and discrete minimal surfaces in particular:

---

[image: Schwartz-P]

      

<sup>[Image](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~springb/discreteminimal/):
A discrete Schwarz-P surface. Bobenko, Hoffmann, Springborn: [2004 arXiv abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305184).</sup>

---

I would be interested in examples where the reverse has happened:
a topic was first substantively explored in a discrete setting,
and only later extended to a continuous setting.
One example—perhaps not the best example—is the contrast
between $n$-body dynamics and galactic dynamics. Of course the former
is hardly "discrete," but rather is more discrete than the study of
[galaxy dynamics leading to the conclusion that there must exist vast
quantities of dark matter](https://sinews.siam.org/Details-Page/dynamics-and-the-dark-matter-mystery-3).

Perhaps there are clearer examples where discrete understanding preceded
continuous exploration?

Comment: Fluid flow, and statistical mechanics more generally?  (Your post suggests you're OK with physical examples.)

Comment: @LSpice: I am fine with physical examples, but wasn't Newton's investigations of fluid mechanics essentially continuous? Of course it is not the case that fluid mechanics originated with Newton. (But I see your point re statistical mechanics.)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, regarding some of Newton's work, see the Darrigol ref, second paragraph of Sec. 1.2.

Comment: Zeno's paradoxes erroneously use discrete arguments to make conclusions about the continuous (change and motion are illusions)?

Comment: Extension of the factorials to the gamma function and, in parallel, the extension of the usual calculus of integral powers of an operator to fractional powers. Related also to generalizing binomial expansions for integral powers to real powers.

Comment: Binary logic to fuzzy logic.

Comment: A similar question on Maths SE: (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1774670) that I asked but had received no answers...

Comment: For an explicitly historical question, the answers here are surprisingly handwavy about history -- of 18 answers, so far only one provides any dates.

Comment: @MattF. I should have mentioned in the posting that if the discrete preceded the development of the relevant continuous mathematics, then it is not as interesting.

Comment: @MattF, you didn't bother to even take a cursory glance at the refs in two of my answers which are replete with dates.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, huh?

Comment: @TomCopeland: 'Tis my fault for an imprecise post, but it is hardly surprising that discrete preceded continuous when continuous approaches didn't exist. I was more interested in the exemplary topology example, where discrete < continuous even though it is conceivable that historically the other order might have prevailed.

Comment: The interest in this question, and the variety of illuminating responses, suggests that an interesting *discrete vs. continuous* history could be written by someone with a sufficiently high-level, broad perspective. (Not me!)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, I would have said informed rather than preceded, as in my examples. Another interesting but vague question would be about where the two are inextricably entwined as in quantum mechanics (wavicles) and in Lie groups and the associated physics where you have countable, distinct, continuous symmetries.

Comment: Related:   Computing the Continuous Discretely by Beck and Robins.

Comment: I will point out that the tag ([tag:discrete-mathematics]) is deprecated (see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/discrete-mathematics/info).) However, I am not sure what would be good replacement in this question.
I have asked for suggestions in chat twice ([here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2017/8/14) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2017/12/5)) but so far I got no feedback there.

Comment: Joe Malkevitch pointed me to this interesting paper by László Lovász: "Discrete and Continuous: Two sides of the same?" He says, "But on a deeper level, there is a more solid connection than meets the eye." ([PDF download](http://web.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/telaviv.pdf).)

Comment: Any objections to my replacing the big-picture tag with big-list?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Sure, go ahead. When I posed it, it was a big-picture issue to me, but it has turned into a big-list. So: Yes.

Comment: Per comment above: A question I posted on a linguistics site illustrates how deeply entrenched notions of discrete structures with well-defined boundaries and continuous substances with no intrinsic boundary are in the English language. Japanese (probably most Asian languages) do not force this distinction (no plural forms even) in speech but do force distinctions in structure in designating the number of discrete structures; e.g., the words for two for two balls, pages, pencils, days, people differ. Somewhat similar to flock, bunch, litter, coven, gaggle, school, pride in English.

Comment: (cont.) English forces abstraction in number allied with mutual distinction/contrast between the structured discrete (countable objects) and the amorphous continuous (not countable substances, but quantifiable by volume, weight, or containers). https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/reference-for-a-standard-systematic-conceptual-categorization-of-count-and-non

Comment: (Revamped earlier comment.) Notions of the discrete and continuous have always evolved hand in hand. To distinguish a discrete apple from another you have to perceive the apple as a continuous, somewhat homogeneous manifold with a well-defined boundary. Tension in the muscles allows humans to directly perceive a continuum in the perception of weight. And so on. "Where Mathematics Comes From" by Lakoff and Nunez offers insights into the interplay of metaphor, mathematics, and perception.

Answer (score 91):

I would say that a lot of topology was discrete before it was continuous. 
The Euler characteristic was first observed (in 1752) as an invariant of
polyhedra. Around 1900 Poincaré first calculated Betti numbers, and 
generalized the Euler characteristic, in a polyhedral setting. The first
general treatment of topology, by Dehn and Heegaard in their Enzyklopädie
article of 1907, was also in a polyhedral setting.

It was only after 1910, with simplicial approximation methods introduced by
Brouwer, that the topological invariance of various combinatorial invariants
was proved. For example, Alexander proved the topological invariance of the
Betti numbers in 1915.

Comment: Excellent example---Thanks!

Comment: And of course the use of geometric flows such as Ricci flow as a continuous method for understanding topology came much later than all of this...

Answer (score 56):

Probability and stochastic processes

Comment: With one recent expansion of the concept of probability being the jump from the Heisenberg/Bohr matrix formulation of quantum mechanics of transitions among discrete states to the Schrodinger rep.in terms of continuous probability amplitudes defined by a differential eqn.

Comment: @TomCopeland, the matrix formulation of quantum mechanics was not Bohr's, and Schrodinger and Heisenberg made their contributions to quantum mechanics independently, so I don't think this is a good example.

Comment: @Mattf,  Planck, Einstein, and Bohr all devloped discrete quantum models preceding and motivating the work of Heisenberg, Born, Kramers, Jordan, and Schrodinger; ergo, the later work can't be considered independent. The devlopment proceeded from models of discrete quantum observables (energy, momentum) to a directly unobservable continuous wave model of probability amplitude.

Comment: Oops, left out de Broglie (1924), rather important.

Comment: @TomCopeland, I agree that the discrete physical understanding preceded Schrodinger.  If the first comment omitted "Heisenberg/" and "matrix" I would agree with that too.

Comment: The most important point is that disctete models led to a paradigm change in our understanding of probability--a revolutionary jump from the classical probability circumscribed by say Kolmogorov to phase interfering quantum probability amplitudes, a radical change made possible only by considering the discrete first.

Comment: and weaving together the discrete and continuous (wavicles).

Comment: @MattF. , in fact, Schrodinger's paper has references to two papers by Heisenberg.

Comment: @TomCopeland, thanks for your feedback

Comment: On the development of QM, see Making 20th Century Science: How Theories Became Knowledge by Stephen G. Brush.

Comment: See also  Darrigol, Olivier. From c-Numbers to q-Numbers: The Classical Analogy in the History of Quantum Theory. Berkeley:  University of California Press,  1992. http://ark.cdlib.org/ark:/13030/ft4t1nb2gv/

Comment: "Quantum Field Theory 1" by Zeidler has a brief account beginning on pg. 60 (The emergence of quantum mechanics) of some of the history w.r.t. probability in QM.

Comment: From pgs. 252-3 of Black-body Theory and the Quantum Discontinuity 1894-1912 by Kuhn (ISBN 0-226-45800-8, pbk): As Bohr`s conception of atomic structure and spectral emission was accepted and became the primary tool for quantum research, ...

Comment: Also see pgs. 447-8 of "Quantum Field Theory Ii" by Zeidler (7.3.3 Quantization of Energy).

Comment: From "The Many Avatars of a Simple Algebra" by Coutinho: At first this equation [Schrodinger's] was hailed as a return to the good old days, with some
physicists hoping that it would drive out those strange matrices and non-commutative quantities [of the Heisenberg-Born-Jordan version of quantum mechanics].

Answer (score 53):

Group theory might be a good example. The first examples of groups were in a discrete setting, namely Galois groups of number fields, which were first understood as permutation groups of the finite set of roots of a polynomial. The emergence of Lie's theory of continuous groups and Klein's Erlangen program came somewhat later (although, in writing this question, I discovered that it was closer than I expected).

Comment: Perhaps you really mean the formalization of group theory began with Galois, yet Abel developed functional equations now called formal group laws. (Euler knew certain elliptc functions are doubly periodic. The integers under addition and subtraction are a group, clock ariithmetic.... The ancients were certanly aware of the symmetry under rotations of circles and squares--the first a continuous symmetry. Prehistorical man didn't think an object's shape was necessarily changed by translation. Babies are surprised if an object passing behind a curtain changes shape--as Noether would've.)

Answer (score 42):

Surely summation of finite discrete series was well-understood, conceptually, long before integration. And I would not be surprised to see similarly for many other ideas of the differential/integral calculus (though not all…).

Comment: Expanding on this, surely the principle "From a discrete series, we can take its differences, and conversely, from any series of putative differences, we may through summation reconstruct the series from which it arises, uniquely up to an additive constant" was understood before the Fundamental Theorem(s) of Calculus.

Comment: Do you have any historical references for such claims, or are you just guessing? Apparently, the summation symbol was introduced later (by Euler) than the integration symbol (Leibniz).

Comment: Although, Leibniz apparently used $\int$ for both integrals and discrete sums. See Cajori, A history of mathematical notations.

Comment: Nothing I mean depends on the sigma or long S symbols for summation; just the concept of addition, "5 + 3 + 8 + 2 + 4 = 22" and so on.

Comment: For what it's worth, Archimedes apparently found the area under a parabola. 2300 years ago. I don't know if you call that integration though.

Comment: @Mehrdad a very specific case of integration I suppose.

Comment: PS Archimedes [link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quadrature_of_the_Parabola).

Comment: The Babylonians also: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2016/01/28/clay-tablets-reveal-babylonians-invented-astronomical-geometry-1400-years-before-europeans/

Answer (score 26):

Integers to rationals to reals.

Comment: In thought perhaps, but 19th century formalisation went in the opposite direction

Comment: There are still tribes whose languages have words for one, two, three, and then only more than three. I'm pretty sure that reflects the natural prehistorical and historical development of thoughts on number from the simple to the complex. The Pythagorean cult was pretty upset with the proof of the existence of irrationals--undermined the authority of their monolithic theory of harmony. The reals, of course, are a continuum of the rationals and irrationals, addressed in decimal form. Don't really give a care about when/how academics put a formal gloss on these ideas--that's not the question.

Comment: Except that if I'm not mistaken it went from positive integers to positive rationals to positive reals, and negative numbers were introduced later by accountants and bankers.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, from the beginning of the notion of number, subtraction has been an important operation as well as motion in opposite directions, so negative numbers have always been implicit in the use of numbers. If the stories are true, even crows/ravens with a number sense of three are clever enough to know after three people have together entered, e.g., a food storage room, when all three have exited individually without being able to see inside the room. Again, a matter of notation and of practice preceding formalism. Negative numbers did not appear out of thin air.

Comment: @TomCopeland : Do you find negative numbers in Euclid or Archimedes?

Comment: @TomCopeland: there are tribes who worship the number zero. Is nothing sacred?

Comment: I'm sure both knew where walking three leagues north and then four leagues south would put them.

Comment: @BenMcKay, ref on that? Intriguing. (Some historians argue about the common narrative on the origin of O as a placeholder.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I meant practice preceded both notation and formalism.

Comment: north 3 leagues + south 4 leagues = south 1 league is equivalent to (+) three leagues + (-) 4 leagues = (-) 1 league.  // As far as accounting goes, I'm sure the tax collectors in Babylon were fond of saying something like "You've given us 10 of 12 bushels of apprised taxes, so you are in debt to us for 2 bushels of wheat. If you shouldn't fulfill your payment by the next full moon, you will find yourself without/minus two of your fingers."

Comment: @TomCopeland : Awareness of subtraction doesn't entail awareness of a concept of negative numbers. When I was in second grade one day the teacher was holding up flash cards with problems of addition and subtraction of one-digit numbers. She came to one that asked for $3-5$ or something like that. People hesitated, then someone said "Zero" and the teacher said that is correct. So I raised my hand and mentioned negative numbers. The teacher said "THERE'S NO SUCH THING AS NEGATIVE NUMBERS IN THE SECOND GRADE!!"

Comment: @MichaelHardy, great anecdote, you're lucky the teacher didn't remove two of your digits--can't say I have much good to say about the vast majority of public or private school teachers. // The idea of having less than nothing was certainly an obstruction to the invention of negative numbers as formulated today. Again, I have to stress the question is about notions of the discrete influencing ideas of the continuous, so heuristics are important. Negative numbers would never have been invented without the related discrete notions I point out in my comments (and maverick students like you).

Comment: There is a reason the negative sign for negative numbers and reversal of the direction of vectors is the same as the minus sign for the operation of subtraction and why nobody questions that.

Answer (score 24):

Theoretical computer science offers lots of examples of what you want, since people almost always think first about the discrete setting, even if the continuous setting also turns out to be important.  Two examples off the top of my head:

[Grover's search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm), one of the central quantum computing algorithms, was first understood in the discrete-time setting and only later in the continuous-time one.  (In an amusing turnabout, the [Farhi-Goldstone-Gutmann algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0702144), which generalizes Grover's algorithm to games of alternation like chess and Go, was first understood in a continuous-time setting and only later in a discrete-time one.)

The number of samples needed to learn a hypothesis was first understood in the discrete case (through the concept of [VC-dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension)), and only later generalized to the continuous case (through the concept of [fat-shattering dimension](http://www.shivani-agarwal.net/Teaching/E0370/Aug-2011/Lectures/5.pdf)).

Answer (score 15):

A recent example would be the generalization of graphs to continuous objects graphons, symmetric measurable functions on a square. Topological properties of spaces of these objects (e.g., compactness) have been shown to yield known properties in the discrete setting (existence of Szemeredi partitions).  Also the continuous setting allows graphons to be interpreted as probability distributions which form a very general model for random graphs.  Such things are detailed in the book of Lovasz, "Large networks and graph limits".

Answer (score 12):

Discrete (more specifically, finite field version) Kakeya conjecture is solved by Zeev Dvir using polynomial method, while original continuous problem is wide open.

If you let me speculate on the reasons, I would say that though we have some ideas what are 'continuous polynomials' (say, Fourier integrals are analogues of trigonometric polynomials), we do not understand what is a right substitute for degree of a polynomial.

Comment: Re: degree of a polynomial—at least in the complex case, what about the winding number?  I guess this privileges certain points above others.

Comment: @LSpice winding is the number of intersections of a curve and a line (well, sign respected). So, it looks to be an invariant in the spirit of "number of roots", in general not well defined for a function which is not a polynomial. Maybe I am too pessimistic.

Answer (score 12):

Another example is coin tossing and other probabilistic models. Coin tossing was studied long before Brownian motion. Discrete probability precedes continuous probability.

Comment: Already mentioned (with less explanation) by [Steve Huntsman](https://mathoverflow.net/a/270937/41291)

Answer (score 10):

In general you seem to be right. Since the invention of Calculus, "continuous" became easier, and usually is investigated before the discrete. One example of the opposite is the differential equations vs difference equations. As I understand the first difference equation studied was the one that defined Fibonacci sequence.
But this was long before Calculus.

EDIT. As I recently learned, Fibonacci discussed this sequence but he did not derive the formula for the general term, did not "solve" the difference equation. It was solved by D. Bernoulli AFTER the invention of calculus. The solution is called Binet formula.

Comment: Calculus itself was built out of earlier discrete ideas, since Newton knew the calculus of finite differences very well, and that informed his methods of interpolation leading him to power series and the rest of calculus as he knew it.

Answer (score 9):

I can think of two good examples. The first is rather straight forward. The hyper-operators. Namely,

$$a \uparrow^n b : \mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N}$$
$$a \uparrow^0 b = a \cdot b$$
$$a \uparrow^n 1 = a$$
$$a \uparrow^{n} (a \uparrow^{n+1} b) = a \uparrow^{n+1} (b+1)$$
$$a \uparrow^{n+1} b = a \uparrow^n a \uparrow^n \cdots (b\text{ times}) \cdots \uparrow^n a$$

It is a rather interesting open problem to construct the same object in analysis. Namely, replace the $\mathbb{N}$'s with some domain in $\mathbb{C}$. Pivotally, tetration, or $e \uparrow^2 z$, is somewhat solved (though controversy exists as to which solution is the right solution). You can perceive the problem better with tetration. It's very easy to get

$$e \uparrow^2 k = e^{e^{\cdots k\text{ times}\cdots^e}}$$

which satisfies

$$e^{e \uparrow^2 k} = e \uparrow^2 (k+1)$$

but how do we get holomorphic $e \uparrow^2 z$? Surely in this scenario the discrete instance inspired the continuous instance.

Another one would be indefinite summation. Everyone knows that

$$\sum_{j=1}^n f(j) = a(n)$$

is well defined, and satisfies $a(n) + f(n+1) = a(n+1)$, but how do we get holomorphic

$$\sum_{j=1}^z f(j) = a(z)$$

where $a(z) + f(z+1) = a(z+1)$. Surely the discrete instance inspired the continuous instance, again.

In fact, the whole field of study dedicating itself to extending recursive relationships defined on the naturals to the complex plane fits the bill of discrete before continuous very well.

Comment: Thanks for bringing in [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), about which I knew little.

Comment: It's a great subject, but the literature is sparse to almost non-existent.

Comment: I went looking for indefinite summation a while ago, spurred by what I don't know, and had a hard time finding anything non-handwavy.  Are there any good expository or introductory papers on it?

Comment: You might have more luck looking at books on finite differences, namely solving the equation $\Delta y = g(z)$. Everything is phrased in a different language, but the problem is the same. The most researched version is probably due to Ramanujan, who solves the case when $|g(z)| < Ce^{\tau|\Im(z)| + \rho|\Re(z)|}$ with $\tau < \pi$. In this case it's called Ramanujan Summation. Ramanujan's notes themselves are handwavy, but enough rigor has been added over the years. Sadly I can't think of any articles off the top of my head. But the keywords Ramanujan Summation is a good starting point.

Answer (score 7):

Investigations of harmonic motion and heat flow (by Huygens, the Bernoullis, Euler, Fourier, et al.) as [discussed](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ae40/2053bc1f9266263435e99acd29588e630985.pdf) in Sections 1.2, 3, and 5 of "The acoustic origins of harmonic analysis" by Olivier Darrigol involved using discrete models as a stepping stone to the continuous.

(This research motivated much work devoted to establishing rigourous foundations of mathematical analysis, such as the definition of a function.)

Comment: More precisely, Lagrange obtained for the first time eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of a homogeneous string by approximating it by a weightless srting with equally spaced beads of equal mass.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, I would say "In particular ... ." There is much earlier and  later work than Lagrange's that is important.

Comment: @Tom Copeland: Who rigorously derived the eigenvalues of a homogeneous string before Lagrange?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, it's just the old forest versus the trees scenario. My answer(s) addresses the question of the discrete scenario informing the continuous not necessarily completely precisely defining it in some selected sense in some limit. No reason to emphasize precise results on spectra here, and, indeed, Lagrange wasn't uninfluenced by his predecessors and contemporaries--he didn't stand alone (he even pays tribute to D Bernoulli). The point is the use of discrete models to draw conclusions, whether heuristic or precise, about associated continuous ones not the exact rigourous results.

Answer (score 7):

To add to the theoretical computer science angle: the study of **graph algorithms** has traditionally been done in a combinatorial setting, because that is way more natural at first of course. But recently our understanding has been greatly aided by methods from linear algebra and continuous optimization, especially in the context of the central to the field maximum flow problem. These insights have in particular lead to the fastest known graph algorithms for certain problems. For some overview of this, see [these](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kppirp11tggl78n/l1_slides.pdf?dl=0) recent slides by Madry.

Answer (score 7):

The main line of inquiry in information theory concerns itself with theoretical limits on data compression for communication and storage, as well as theoretical limits on transmission rates for noise-resilient communication (or fault-tolerant computing, etc.). Claude Shannon's famous 1948 paper, which lays the foundation for the field rather comprehensively, concerns itself entirely with discrete information sources (that is discrete in both time and state space), modeled as stochastic processes. Later treatments (even until now) remain much more concerned with discrete information sources. As far as I know, there is substantial treatment of continuous sources (especially continuous state-space), but it was not pursued first and it remains secondary.

Answer (score 6):

Fredholm integral equations of the first kind can be viewed as continuous analogues of matrix multiplication of a vector. The use of the terminology for matrices, such as the trace and determinant, for integral kernels are vestiges of the development from the discrete to the continuous as [explained](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:303480/FULLTEXT01.pdf) in "On the origin and early history of functional analysis" by Lindstrom (see in particular Section 4).

Comment: +1 even though I hate using the matrix representation, and hate when one has to digest a proof in terms of matrices.

Comment: @james.nixon, I think it is important for students wishing to become innovators (in any field) to appreciate the struggles/messiness of creation not  just the beauty of the final product.

Comment: I'm all for that... except when it involves matrices ;)

Comment: @james.nixon, I'm reminded, on the other hand, of some anecdote (maybe by Rota or Arnold) of a researcher who dismissively said, "I do discrete not continuous."

Comment: See also the discussion of Volterra's composition law on p. 34 of "Some highlights in the development of algebraic analysis" by Synowiec (https://eudml.org/doc/209068) that draws a similarv analogy between matrix multiplication and integrals.

Comment: Reading about Sylvester and Cayley and their interest in invariant theory, I just learned that determinants represented as two dimensional arrays of numbers/coefficients preceded the construction of matrices as computational devices encoding ways of multiplying arrays of numbers/variables/indeterminates.

Comment: The anecdote must have been Rota's. From a short bio of R by Kung: In the early 1960s, the start of his second period, Rota’s interest shifted to combinatorics,  a subject he was fond of describing as “putting balls into boxes.” He became “one of the 
many who unknotted themselves from the tentacles of the Continuum and joined the 
then Rebel Army of the Discrete."

Comment: "Joseph Fourier’s first model of heat diffusion, which led to his series, marked the origin of infinite matrix theory, a topic which did not really develop until the late nineteenth century, closely driven by functional analysis and integral equations. In this context the name “spectral theory” has its origins." -- From the Rise of the Group Concept to the Stormy Onset of Group Theory in the New Quantum Mechanics by Bonolis.

Answer (score 6):

Quantum field theory is a very cogent example of contemporary interest: Path integrals and quantum fields on a lattice are easy to define (and [lattice quantum chromodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD) is a big industry nowadays), but establishing even a good definition for the continuum analogs has proved hitherto elusive.  You can [win a million dollars](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/yang%E2%80%93mills-and-mass-gap) for proving that such a continuum field theory exists.

Answer (score 5):

> In general you seem to be right. Since the invention of Calculus,
>   "continuous" became easier, and usually is investigated before the
>   discrete. One example of the opposite is the differential equations vs
>   difference equations. As I understand the first difference equation
>   studied was the one that defined Fibonacci sequence. But this was long
>   before Calculus.

On the contrary, I would argue this is a wholly 'modern' 20th century perspective. Pretty much all the great mathematical-physicists that introduced major classes of new mathematical tools, from Newton to Maxwell to Feynman, were very much constructive mathematicians, in their thinking (Einstein comes to mind as a counterexample; sure there are more).

Newton pretty much hated infinitesimal calculus, and wrote all his original proof in terms of finite geometrical constructions; that the differential algebraic method was a more convenient method of obtaining the same results is definitely the opinion of people that came after him, not of the guy that came up with the original logic of it.

Maxwell preferred to think about vector calculus in terms of finite elements / mechanical gears; and if I had to teach someone electrodynamics today, I would most certainly prefer to do it using discrete exterior calculus rather than using vector calculus (and similarly, einstein notwithstanding, I think Regge calculus is a lot more instructive than differential tensor equations).

The same applies to Feynman. His methods were developed using discrete logic; and he was highly critical of the logical acrobatics required to make sense of the UV divergences as you take the limit to continuous space.

Comment: "Newton pretty much hated infinitesimal calculus, and wrote all his original proof in terms of finite geometrical constructions" could you provide some references for this?

Comment: Cant find the exact quote I was thinking about, but this book review covers quite a bit of it: http://ndpr.nd.edu/news/isaac-newton-on-mathematical-certainty-and-method/

Excerpt: 'Newton also developed a strong dislike for algebraic computations that, according to legend, he called "the mathematics of bunglers," and he insisted that mathematics, to be certain, had to be expressed in geometrical form.'

Comment: It seems that Newton preferred "geometry" over "algebra". Which --to my mind-- are different opposite than "discrete" vs. "continuous". At least that's how I interpret the review you linked to.

Comment: No, those are indeed not exact synonyms, but for the purposes of this question they are more or less. His aversion did explicitly stem from a formulation in terms of infinitesimals, as opposed to finite geometrical constructions. Either way, he himself did certainly not present the explicitly continuous differential formulation as the crux to understanding his subject matter, but rather as an awkward tool.

Comment: Do you have a reference for Maxwell's or any subsequent development of electrodynamics using finite elements/mechanical gears? That would be very interesting. Any treatment would be worth looking at).

Comment: Newton said a lot of things. Do you really believe the story of the falling apple? For a guy who discovered so much of analytic importance, I can't seriously take any claim that he was truly averse to analytic methods  as opposed to geometric even if he indeed claimed that. I do think he became weary of concentrating on math in his later years. See the intro to Needham's Visual Complex Analysis on some related thoughts.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold, from Wikipedia: "Chandrasekhar worked on a project devoted to explaining the detailed geometric arguments in ... Newton's ... Principia Mathematica using the language and methods of ordinary calculus. The effort resulted in the book Newton's Principia for the Common Reader, published in 1995."  // Geometric proofs were de rigeur in Newton's time and he had some difficulty getting his work on calculus published.

Comment: (cont) That and priority disputes embittered him somewhat to the point that "standing on the shoulders of giants" may have been an oblique gibe at a disputant  (http://io9.gizmodo.com/5877660/was-robert-hooke-really-sciences-greatest-asshole) as well as the bunglers quote (e.g., Isaac Newton on Mathematical Certainty and Method by Niccolò Guicciardini). See also the Needham ref and maybe a bio by White on my points.

Comment: See p. 415 of The Cambridge Companion to Newton on bungling algebraists (I'm sympathetic, lol). I would say Newton advocated mathematics informed by physical intuition, of which  geometry is one form and his calculus another (motion, flux--geometry and time), over pure algebraic manipulation, as does Arnold, Weinberg, and others.

Comment: On Newton, see also https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/best-books-papers-on-newton-and-his-mathematical-physics.

Comment: And the always stimulating Arnol'd in "Huyghens and Barrow, Newton and Hooke" with his signature provocative asides.

Comment: Needham in the preface to his new book on differential geometry makes further remarks about Newton, calculus, and the Principia.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much every [Analytic Continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) from the integer, or other discrete, into real (or other continuous) domain is an example of this.

The [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) extending the factorial into real domain is a classic example of analytic continuation, but there are many more.

$\Gamma (n) = (n-1)!$

${\displaystyle \Gamma (z)=\int _{0}^{\infty }x^{z-1}e^{-x}\,dx}  $

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO. Can you add more details about your answer?

Comment: Already mentioned in the comments to the question. For development see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/why-is-eulers-gamma-function-the-best-extension-of-the-factorial-function-to/133194#133194

Comment: @TomCopeland: Analytic continuation? Where? Analytic continuation is a whole large class or problems which fall under the titular question, gamma is just one common example.

Comment: The extension of the Euler integral to Re(z)  < 0 is an example of analytic continuation of a function analytic and therefore continuous and smooth in some domain to a larger domain. The extension of values at discrete points to a continuum is an example of interpolation, as in the MSE answer and links which is the thrust of my earlier comment.

Answer (score 3):

Benjamini-Schramm convergence was originally defined for graphs, later extended to metric spaces with applications especially in the setting of locally symmetric spaces. See http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2017/185-3/p01

Answer (score 3):

***The Riemann zeta function is a prime example.***

Far into antiquity are investigations of partial sums of integral powers of the natural numbers, leading eventually to the Bernoulli polynomials and the discovery of their exponential generating function by Euler. It was natural to then look at partial sums of the reciprocals of the natural integers.

From Wikipedia:

*The Basel problem is a problem in mathematical analysis with relevance to number theory, first posed by Pietro Mengoli in 1650 and solved by Leonhard Euler in 1734, and read on 5 December 1735 in The Saint Petersburg Academy of Sciences. ...
The Basel problem asks for the precise summation of the reciprocals of the squares of the natural numbers, i.e. the precise sum of the infinite series:*

$$ \sum_{n>0} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Excerpt from "On some historical aspects of the theory of the Riemann zeta function" by Giuseppe Iurato:

*Euler's application of infinite series to different number theoretical problems was of principal importance. The study
of the series $ \frac{1}{n^{2k}}$ leads to series of the form $ \frac{1}{n^s}$. ....
Euler (1707-1783) was probably the first to see that these series can be applied to number theory. He was in correspondence with C. Goldbach and J.L Lagrange just on number theory questions. His proof of the existence of infinitely many primes uses the divergence of the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ and using the above fundamental theorem of arithmetic which says that every natural number can uniquely be written as a product of powers of primes. Afterwards, P.L.G. Dirichlet (1805-1859) systematically introduced analytical methods in number theory. Among other things, he investigated the series $ \frac{1}{n^s}$ for real $s$, while B. Riemann (1826-1866) allowed complex $s$.*

There is also Euler's formula for reflection symmetry of the nascent Riemann $\xi$ function.

It is precisely the e.g.f. for the Bernoulli numbers that appears in Riemann's integral formula for $(s-1)! \zeta(s)$, as he was well aware of.

Comment: "The Riemann zeta function is a prime example." Pun intended?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, primarily.

Comment: More detail in "Euler's constant: Euler's work and modern developments" by Lagarias https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1856

Comment: I believe Dirichlet's initial should be P.G.L. rather than P.L.G.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, actually I  don't recall ever having seen Dirichlet's initials before. Same for Lagrange--strange habit of writing. Perhaps Mr., Ms, Dr., Prof., 'illustrious, unspecified binary person' (for Californians) should be included.

Answer (score 2):

From SKETCHES OF KDV by E. Arbarello:

Studying a dynamical system consisting of a finite number of particles of unitary mass distributed along a line segment with forces acting on adjacent pairs, Fermi, Pasta and Ulam introduced a natural non-linear perturbation which gave rise to an unexpected, discrete version of the KdV equation. Starting from this model, ten years later, Zabusky and Kruskal [ZK65] undertook a numerical study of the KdV which exhibited, for the first time, solutions of KdV having the appearence of packets of N localized waves which collide and resurrect in the same way as Scott Russel’s waves do in a shallow canal. Because of the particle-like behaviour of these collisions, they named these solutions: N-solitons.

Answer (score 1):

One of Ramanujan's favorite insights on how the discrete informs the continuous is described in my reply to the MO-Q "[Ramanujan's Master Formula: A proof and relation to umbral calculus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379428/ramanujans-master-formula-a-proof-and-relation-to-umbral-calculus/379453#379453)."

Surmising the Mellin transform of $f(t)$ from the coefficients of the Taylor series expansion about the origin of $f(-t)$ is a beautiful heuristic, which I've yet to see incorporated into tables of Mellin transforms. (Hardy gave a formal presentation of this heuristic after noting R's use of it.)